# CSS selector to get preceding sibling

Tags: css, class, dom, element

Is there any way using pure CSS(3) to select an element that is a preceding sibling of an element with a particular class?

i.e.:

html:

```
<div id='element-to-find'></div>
<div id='box1'></div>
<!-- a bunch more DOM elements between here --->
<div id='box2'>
      <div id='inner-box'></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#box1{ /*some styling*/ }
#box2{ /*some styling*/ }

#box2.active .....
```

Now, when #box2 has the class `active` I want to select and do something to the style of `#element-to-find`.  Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Comment: There is no "previous sibling" selector in CSS, so probably not

Comment: Would you consider making the element-to-find have an active class as well?

Comment: If element to find is after `#box2`, you can achieve it. The previous sibling selector, as it has been mentioned, doesn't exists (yet!): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing any more of your selectors, you could potentially use CSS's :not() selector.

```
div:not(#box1), div:not(#box2) {
    /*some style here*/
}
```

I would just suggest giving your `#element-to-find` a class as well when you select box2 and have a style ready for it.

Answer (score 6):

There were multiple proposals to CSSWG in www-style@w3.org mailing list as for previous-sibling combinator: [my one](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Jan/1245.html) (2012), another [1](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2013Feb/0279.html), [2](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2013Apr/0074.html) (2013).

Common answer by Tab Atkins is like "we already have subject indicator for this". For selecting *descendants* of previous sibling (which would be trivial with previous-sibling combinator, e.g. `.example - UL > LI`), he suggests to use `:matches()` functional pseudoclass, e.g. `:matches(!UL + .example) > LI`. Both subject indicator and `:matches()` are currently in draft state and cannot be used in real world yet.

So you should add a regular class to the `element-to-find` element or (much less desired if your `active` class is added not via JS) use JavaScript to emulate previous-sibling-combinator functionality.